# What is the most popular general purpose C++ framework?

Tags: c++, frameworks

I was looking at Qt and came to wondering, what is the most popular general purpose C++ framework, and what are some pros and cons of it?

Comment: What kind of framework? Are you talking about GUI toolkits like Qt and GTK specifically?

Comment: @Thomas - Would it be too broad to say the best general purpose toolkit?

Comment: In that case it must be Boost.

Comment: You need to be more specific about *what kind* of framework you're talking about. I imagine you're talking about GUI frameworks, but there are C++ frameworks that have nothing to do with GUIs.

Comment: In your comment you changed the question from "most popular" to "best". Was that your intent?  Either way, still too vague, since you could say use Boost with, say, Qt; They are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 25):

The [STL](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/start) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) are both pretty popular, and they're pretty much the epitome of "general purpose".

Comment: Is boost a framework? I think it's just a library collection.

Comment: are they considered "frameworks"? Beyond that - somewhat academic - quesiton, I agree.

Comment: @peter - I don't feel so. I'm looking for something to truly get my teeth stuck in to, and wouldn't mind having a good starting point.

Comment: Meh, that's why it's Community Wiki. "General-purpose framework" to me does sort of sound like a library, hence my answer.

Comment: IMO framework = skeleton you have to fill, library = lego blocks. But as said, that's somewhat academic, as the distinction isn't black / white.

Answer (score 15):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/library) is very popular. It's available under open-source (LGPL) and commercial licenses, has fully-featured core and GUI class libraries and an integrated IDE and build system. It's also cross-platform.

It's under very active development and has a new declarative UI library ([QtQuick](http://blog.qt.nokia.com/2010/02/15/meet-qt-quick/) including [QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarativeui.html)) due in the next release (4.7).

Definitely worth checking out for new projects.

For Windows-only work [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.71).aspx) is still worth a look. It's recently been updated.

Comment: I would like to stress that the GUI class libraries are a fraction of what the overall Qt framework offers.

Answer (score 8):

The question as it stands is probably unanswerable; you'll probably end up with a list of people's interpretation of "framework" with no real way for distinguishing them.

Perhaps we need a definition of framework?  I suggest it is *a library that in some way determines the architecture of an entire application*.  However that is perhaps a definition of "[Application Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_framework)", but if you mean the term more broadly, then the question is probably too broad.  This definition however makes say Qt a framework, while Boost remains just a library.  That makes Boost no more or less useful, so I really don't understand what you are trying to discover from the question.

Here's a list of UI related libraries that *might* be considered "frameworks":

- [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library)
- [.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)
- [WxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets)
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)
- [KDE](http://www.kde.org/)
- [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME)
- [TurboVision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision)  ;-)

The most notable distinguishing feature is that some of them are cross-platform, and some are platform specific. Gnome is perhaps distinguished by having a C API (GTK+). .Net supports multiple languages, but requires C++/CLI rather than ISO C++ (but that is no worse than Qt's pre-processor IMO).  MFC is a bit long in the tooth and not supported by free or third-party tools. TurboVision is antique and included for my amusement and geek nostalgia.

Comment: [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) (object-oriented framework for developing Microsoft Windows applications), [FireMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey) (cross-platform GUI Framework)

Comment: **GNOME** and **KDE** are not UI libraries, they are _Desktop Environments_. KDE uses **Qt** _application framework_, and GNOME uses **GTK** _widget toolkit_, but GTK is not a C++ library, therefore **gtkmm** is a C++ wrapper for GTK. Also KDE and GNOME have their own custom libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but I found it very useful.
I would like to add [PoCo](http://pocoproject.org) (POrtable COmponents) to the list

I used it for seleral projects and includes a consistent and well designed framework for:

1. XML
2. Multi threading
3. Networking
4. Cryptography
5. General purposes

It is also portable (I used it on Windows and Unix).